# Laravel 7 adminLTE Argument 1 passed::__construct() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I try to install and user adminLTE 3 for Laravel 7.

I have this error :

```
Argument 1 passed to JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\AdminLte::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hedrinenew/vendor/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte/src/AdminLteServiceProvider.php on line 23 (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hedrinenew/resources/views/adminlte.blade.php)
```

I followed the instructions of this page : https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE

That's  not the first time I install and use adminLTE, but that's the first time I have a problem.

Comment: What is the version of laravel you are using?

Comment: Laraval 7.9.2 thank you.

Comment: Do you have the config file?

Comment: Yes, I have the config file... <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Title
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you can change the default title of your admin panel.
    |
    | For more detailed instructions you can look here:
    | https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/#61-title
    |
    */

    'title' => 'AdminLTE 3',
    'title_prefix' => '',
    'title_postfix' => '',...

Comment: What is on this? `AdminLteServiceProvider.php on line 23 `

Comment: $app['config']['adminlte.filters'], on line 23 of this file....

Comment: Try this: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider" --tag=config

Comment: Thank you, this is the mesage Unable to locate publishable resources.

Comment: Try `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\AdminLteServiceProvider" --tag=config`

Comment: https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#6-configuration

Comment: Thank you, Always the same error : Unable to locate publishable resources.

Comment: The only option I guess is: `php artisan adminlte:install --type=full`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213041/discussion-between-david-and-sachin-bahukhandi).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem resolved with this code :

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```